# Adicionar + 1 à uma variável e acessar páginas diferentes dependendo do valor

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou tentando criar um código que me comece com o valor 0, e a cada vez que ele entra no google, por exemplo, o valor é aumentado em 1, e cada vez que o valor aumenta, o codigo acessa uma página diferente. Eu consegui um código para tirar como base, mas não estou entendendo onde que está o nome da variável e como fazer com que o script faça o redirecionamento.

```
 var count = 0;//recebendo o valor 5 que você disse
 $('#addCount').click(function(){
 alert(count);
 count++;
 });
```

edit:

Ok, na realidade eu quero utilizar esse codigo para acessar diversos e-mails, de provedores diferentes, que eu possuo. Recebo atualizações regulares durante o dia de determinados sites, e o meu objetivo é deixar um computador alheio na minha sala que, sozinho, acessa as minhas caixas de entradas nesses provedores, os atualizando a todo momento. Caso eu receba o e-mail que eu precisse, o meu script em autoIT irá me avisar através de um beep.

Tendo dito isso, no caso do javascript, eu espero apenas que ele acesse o gmail.com, depois acesse o yahoo.com, depois acesse o uol.com, e depois o bol.com. Quero que o script rode nessa ordem, como um loop.

Eu acredito que isso só seria possível caso eu utilizasse um contador.

Alguem poderia em ajudar? obrigado!

Comment: _"e a cada vez que ele entra no google"_ - podes explicar melhor? queres que a página saiba e continue a contar quando tiveres ido para outra página?

Comment: Eu quero que o script acesse paginas diferentes e especificas a cada vez que o contador subir, por exemplo:

contador = 0
acessar o google

contador = 1
acessar o yahoo

contador = 2
acessar o bol

contador = 3
acessar o stackflow

contador = 4
esperar uma hora
zerar contador.

Comment: Abrindo janelas novas ou redirecionando aquela em que o utilizador estiver? tens uma lista de sites com o nr que o `count` deve ter para cada um?

Comment: Redirecionando mesmo, sem abrir janelas novas.

Comment: Nesse caso perdes o contador, quando redirecionas o código que conta os cliques perde-se.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção.
Na verdade eu peguei este codigo já com a função do clique. Eu tentei tira-lá para contar apenas quando eu acessar a pagina atráves da url, mas não obtive sucesso. Dessa forma o contador seria perdido também? Por que?

Comment: Cada página nova tem o seu próprio código e o código anterior é descartado. Explica toda a funcionalidade que queres que talvez seja mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Editei o meu post com o que eu quero que o script faça, não sem bem se deixei claro o que espero conseguir fazer com o código por eu não entender muito bem a linguagem e termos usados entre programadores visto que estou entrando na área agora, mas toda a paciência será apreciada.

Comment: Caso não seja possível utilizar o contador guiado pelas paginas, eu poderia uzá-lo a partir de elementos, que são diferentes em cada uma delas.

Comment: @PauloRicardo, é possível fazer o que deseja usando o `TamperMonkey`, você pode ver algo semelhante no [Gmail POP3 Checker](https://www.danielslaughter.com/projects/gmail-pop3-checker-for-greasemonkey/)